# Is there a simple way to create a hash of list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, hash, python-2.7

I have a list containing dictionaries, which in turn might contain other lists and/or dictionaries, example

```
a =  [{3:4},{1:2}, {5:[5,6,7,7]} ]
```

I would like to create a hash sum (or something equivalent) of this object in order to compare it to another hash, which is different when the content of the list is different.

I need this to make queries over the network. Instead of pulling the probably very large lists over the network all the time, I just get the hash-sum, and only when this sum differs from the previous hash-sum I get the entire list over the network.

Is there some easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: "probably very large" - are they large? How large is large?

Comment: The quick & dirty way would be `hashlib.sha256(pickle.dumps(a)).digest()`, I guess.

Comment: If the hashes must be all unique, you'll ultimately end up with enormous hashes and not save any traffic. You have to choose a reasonable size for the hash and deal with the possibility of having hash collisions.

Comment: `hashlib.sha256(pickle.dumps(a)).digest()` would depend on the order of the iteration through the dictionairy

Comment: @all: thanks for the input, I guess just polling the original object might be fine in my case, as the objects are not the sizes of megabytes anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pickle

```
hashlib.md5(pickle.dumps(a[0])).hexdigest()
```

str does not always give the expected result

Answer (score 1):

How about doing something like:

```
# imports
import copy

def make_hash(x):
     # Check if arg is a list, tuple or set
     if isinstance(x, (set, tuple, list)):
         return tuple([make_hash(y) for y in x])

     # Check if arg is not a dict
     elif not isinstance(x, dict):
         return hash(x)

     new = copy.deepcopy(x)
     for k,v in new.items():
         new[k] = make_hash(v)
     return hash(tuple(frozenset(new.items())))
```

and then you can simply do `make_hash([{...},{...}])`

Answer (score 0):

```
a =  [{3:4},{1:2}, {5:[5,6,7,7]} ]
hash(str(a))
```